# Error: No such file or directory in pom.xml document

Tags: pom.xml

I am getting the above error in my pom.xml document. I have tried the solutions described in,
    [pom.xml no such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14868172/) pom-xml-no-such-file-or-directory. But the error is not rectified. Can anyone suggest me with the solution?

Comment: Provide detail for the exception from console

Comment: Can't get what you are asking? Whether you need the code? or the brief description of my problem?

Comment: It shows the error at top of the editor in pom.xml file. And it displays build failure when i try to build my project using the command Maven->Maven Build

Comment: This is the content displayed in console.